# How to align several text and images in CSS

Tags: html, css

Have a look at this screenshot for my problem:

[image]

This is the html code:

```
   <div class="parent_process">  
      <div class="first_process"><img src="images/exprimer-besoin-telephonie.png"/><span style="width:18%">Vous remplissez le formulaire pour exprimer votre besoin (env 1 min)</span></div>  
      <div class="second_process"><img src="images/contacter-tous-les-vendeurs-autocommutateurs.png"/><span style="width:18%">Vous remplissez le formulaire pour exprimer votre besoin (env 1 min)</span></div>  
     <div class="third_process"><img src="images/recevoir-offre-standard-telephonique-pas-cher.png"/><span style="width:18%">Vous remplissez le formulaire pour exprimer votre besoin (env 1 min)</span></div>  
</div>
```

This is css code:

```
.parent_process{ width:100%; white-space:nowrap; }
.parent_process div{ display:inline-block; width:33.3%;}
.first_process{ text-align:left; }
.second_process{ text-align:center; }
.third_process{ text-align:right; }
```

How can I have my 3 columns:
1)my text 1 |  2) my text 2  |  3) my text 3

Someone can help please?

Regards

Comment: `white-space:nowrap;` doesn't allow your text to break in lines then the content is overlapping the others.

Comment: You would want something like `overflow: auto` if you want to use `white-space: nowrap` without it overlapping other text.

Answer (score 1):

Your three containers are the correct width, but the `whitespace: nowrap` style prevents the text from wrapping. So with overflow showing it just spills over.

If you remove `whitespace: nowrap`, your text will stay within the width of the container. However, you will notice a new problem. The columns do not fit on a single row:
http://jsfiddle.net/q1g0uxx4/2/

This is because the columns will have almost no space in between - not even space for a single character. With `inline block`, that causes them to wrap

You can remove all the whitespace between your divs, and they will fit:
http://jsfiddle.net/q1g0uxx4/1/

This isn't great for formatting though. Another way is to set the font-size of your container to 0.1px. Then it will fit even with formatted markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/q1g0uxx4/3/

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using bootstrap as your css framework. They have a nice column system in place.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/4dfkb0Ln/)

The css is as simple as `col-sm-4`.

```
<div class='col-sm-4'>
    <img src='http://ethanwiner.com/Smiley%20Land/Frenchie.gif' />some type of stuff that you can type some type of stuff that you can type</div>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
    <img src='http://ethanwiner.com/Smiley%20Land/Frenchie.gif' />some type of stuff that you can type some type of stuff that you can type</div>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
    <img src='http://ethanwiner.com/Smiley%20Land/Frenchie.gif' />some type of stuff that you can type some type of stuff that you can type</div>
```