# How align several texts and images without flex

Tags: css

There are several subjects on StackOverFlow as here, but the answers are not intuitive for a beginner.

[How to align several text and images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442045/how-to-align-several-text-and-images-in-css)

[How to align several text and images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442045/how-to-align-several-text-and-images-in-css)

Actually, I would like to center 2 images on the same line, in bottom of each image there are a title and a subtitle. I would like to make it without `display: flex`.

I don't understand why the seconde image is not aligned horizontally correctly?

[image]

```css
.row{
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;

}

.imgP{
  background-color:red;
  margin: auto 5px;
  
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <img class="imgP" src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/18/te8n.png" alt="image">  
      <div class="title">My title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
      <img class="imgP" src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/18/te8n.png" alt="image">  
      <div class="title">My title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
   </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: have you tried `display:grid;`? Flex would be the alternative, but since you don't want to use it, the final way I can think of will have to be using positioning (which is not a very good practice)

Comment: inline block...

Comment: @Sagar V: I have tried `display:inline-block`, but I don't know on what class in fact?

Comment: because in HTML, we are in a textual logic and not in a graphical interface logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is the easy and modern way to do it. If you don't want to use flex, use `display:inline-block`. For that, you need to create 2 column divs and wrap the content inside it.

```css
.row {
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgP {
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="imgP" src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/18/te8n.png" alt="image">
      <div class="title">My title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="imgP" src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/18/te8n.png" alt="image">
      <div class="title">My title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I understood !